# Centered full screen html image (not an image in css)

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I'm trying to have a full screen image, easy enough with css using the code below.

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: url('photo2.jpg'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

but the image is already placed in an html div, see here

```
<div class="fixed-background">
  <img src="photo2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

It need's to be exactly how it would be using the css version, the only difference would be the image is called in html and not in the stylesheet.

Comment: u want to do the same keeping image in html??

Comment: Yes, the image is added in wordpress and can't be added to the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<style>
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fixed-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myimg {
    height: inherit;
}
</style>

<html>
<body>
    <div class="fixed-background">
        <img src="public/dbs/images/1.jpg" class="myimg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `object-fit: cover;` on the `<img>` tag:

```
<div>
  <img src="photo2.jpg" style="object-fit: cover;"/>
</div>
```

that parameter is a rather new thing (not all browsers supported), but that's the way to go. See also http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

Without using a background, consider this:

```
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; /* (calculate half the height of your image) */
    margin-left: -100px; /* (calculate half the width of your image) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full screen Image? you could do something like this through HTML

```
<div class="fixed-background">
  <img src="photo2.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pj73m4po/

EDIT:

or are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/pj73m4po/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: http://jsfiddle.net/pj73m4po/4/

Put your image in a div 100% high and wide. If you don't want your image to be stretched you don't want to use width and height seperately.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fixed-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Instead use min-width and min-height. if you have a predefined image you can adjust the position in css. If you don't unfortunately you need javascript to center it.

Answer (score 0):

The points that I gather from your css are the following:

- Center the image
- Fix the position of the image (so it doesn't scroll with the page)
- Cover the viewport, scale proportionally to fit

That said, I suggest the following given your html

```
.fixed-background{
   position:fixed;
   width:100vh;
   height:100vh;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.fixed-background > img{
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Honestly, I haven't tested the above but I would suspect you might get some weird results using fixed and absolute positioning together. But since the code defines the width and height directly using viewport units, it should be good. You might need `100vh` of margin applied to a sibling element to get things to line up because `position:fixed;` will break the element out of the document flow.